# How much does a new Wii U Wind Waker bundle edition have to download in order to play?

Tags: wii-u, zelda-wind-waker

I'm planning to buy a Wii U and the LOZ Wind Waker bundle edition seems like a nice deal, but as far as I know the bundle does not come with a physical copy of the game, so you have to download it along with some Wii U firmware updates. Since I live abroad and the internet in my country is pretty bad, downloading could take ages or get cancel due to service downtime.

So the question is: How much does the Wii U have to download, in gigabytes, including the game, updates and other in order to play Wind Waker?

Comment: The answer to this question will change over time, depending on how many firmware updates have happened since the Wind Waker bundle released.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I installed the game on my Wii U and I can't check right now, but I'm quite sure the size is around 2.5 GB plus/minus a few MB due to compression and such.

Comment: According to [NintendoLife](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2013/09/heres_how_much_space_zelda_the_wind_waker_hd_will_take_up_on_your_wii_u) the game is 1792 MB

Comment: Hm yes, definitely possible. The download size might have been 1.7 GB and the install size 2.5 GB.

Comment: Does that include system updates?

Comment: Do you mean patches for the game? Or updates for the overal system? As for the latter, we can't say, because we don't know when you updated your system the last time.

Answer (score -6):

You can check out how much the software is in Gigabytes on the eShop. I'm not sure how big it is, but I think it's around 3.5 GB. But I do know that when I bought the bundle, it took about an hour to download (not to mention Wii U updates, etc) at my house and we have pretty good bandwidth. So it'll probably take a long time to download, but it's by far my favorite Zelda game and a must-have for any gamer. It's certainly worth the wait. And the controller! It's the most beautiful thing in the world (except my wife, of course). Also, the Bundle costs the same as a normal Wii U, so you basically get the Wind Waker for free. I usually keep hard copies of all my games for nostalgic purposes, or if I don't like it I can return or sell it, but if you don't have a problem with that, I'd definitely buy the LOZ Windwaker Wii U Bundle.